# How can I output erasable text in c++ to console?

Tags: c++

I remember seeing completed programs where you could backspace and delete text prompts. Usually, all text that is cout'ed is static and cannot be erased from the screen, but I want to be able to erase text that was output by the program (such as, for example, the program gives me a default name that I can accept, or delete and enter my own). I would imagine I could fake keyboard input to put up erasable text on the console, but is there a cleaner way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Warning: The answer you get will probably not be portable.

Comment: I don't quite understand why is there a problem to put '\b' into cout.

Comment: /b is getting there. I want to be able to shift my cursor to any letter of the default text, without being forced to rewrite the entire thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, you probably want something like [GNU Readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)

> "The GNU Readline library provides a
>   set of functions for use by
>   applications that allow users to edit
>   command lines as they are typed in.
>   Both Emacs and vi editing modes are
>   available. The Readline library
>   includes additional functions to
>   maintain a list of previously-entered
>   command lines, to recall and perhaps
>   reedit those lines, and perform
>   csh-like history expansion on previous
>   commands."

Comment: That actually sounds like pretty exactly what I wanted. Thanks Kitsune!